# Using javascript Regexp object to replace a value in url

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currstr = "?distance=10&city=Boston&criteria=shoes&size=10";
var selcity = "California"; //This can come from a drop down

var pat = new RegExp([NEEDPATTERN],"gi");
currstr.replace(pat,selcity);
</script>
```

I need some help replacing city=Boston in `currstr` with a value user selects from 
drop down, right now I have hardcoded value in var selcity. I have placed a [NEEDPATTERN] marker for pattern that can be used to achieve this.

Can someone help me with this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to replace "Boston" specifically, or do you need to just replace the `X` in `city=X`?

For boston, you can just use simple substitution... `currstr.replace('Boston', selcity)`

For replacing `X`, you can do: `currstr.replace(/city=([^&]+)/, selcity);`

Comment: Awesome!!. This currstr.replace(/city=([^&]+)/, selcity); works. I wanted to replace any X with new value. Thank you all.!!

Answer (score 1):

```
/City=([^&]+)/gi
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, rather than replacing you should leave city out entirely and tack it on at the end. Then you don't have to deal with regexing which could be more complicated than the current answers if you take into account entities like `&amp;`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var currstr = "?distance=10&criteria=shoes&size=10";
 var selcity = "California"; //This can come from a drop down

 currstr += "&city=" + encodeURIComponent(selcity);
</script>
```